# How to perform NSUndoManager on NSMutableArray which contains Images?(Objective - C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsmutablearray, nsundomanager

I'm creating an iOS App in which user can add effects to images. After applying that effect I've one `done` button which saves the current effect and allows user to add next effect on already applied effect, so user can apply more effects on other effects. If user won't press `Done` button then he switches between effects but with "Done" button he can apply effect on effect(Hope you get it!). Now I've two extra buttons named `Undo` & `Redo`. I'm saving all applied effects in an `array` when user clicks on `done` button.

Now I want to undo applied effects when `undo` button is clicked. And visa versa redo operation when `redo` button is clicked.

I know for that purpose I've to use `NSUndoManager` but I don't know from where I should start means I don't know how to use `NSUndoManager` with Array which contains Images?

Comment: Please go through link : http://szulctomasz.com/2015/09/13/ios-undo-and-redo-with-nsundomanager.html

Comment: @AshokLondhe I've already referred this one but its in swift and I'm not much familiar with swift so not getting idea from that. thanx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've done this by different way!! besides using `NSUndoManager` I've just used 2 `Arrays` and done code with them.

```
- (IBAction)onUndoClicked:(id)sender {    
 if ([arrUndo lastObject] == nil) {
        NSLog(@"EMPTY");
    }
    else
    {
        [arrRedo addObject:[arrUndo lastObject]];
        NSLog(@"ArrAdd %@", [arrUndo description]);

        [arrUndo removeLastObject];
        for (UIImage *obj in arrUndo) {
            if ([arrUndo lastObject] == obj) {

                _imgClicked.image =  obj;
            }
        }
    }}

- (IBAction)onRedoClicked:(id)sender {

    if ([arrRedo lastObject] == nil) {
        NSLog(@"EMPTY");
    }
    else
    {
        [arrEffectImages addObject:[arrRedo lastObject]];
        for (UIImage *obj in arrRedo) {
            if ([arrRedo lastObject] == obj) {
                _imgClicked.image =  obj;
            }
        }
    }}
```